# TRIAC not triggering in 3rd quadrant but works perfectly in 1st

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, triac, diac

Good day. I am designing a power control circuit for dimming a 100W bulb using BTA16. In the circuit shown below, when I apply power to the circuit I only receive the positive pulse at the output (of both MOC3020 and the Triac, triggered perfectly at the desired angle) but it completely blocks the negative cycle. (Circuit and output diagrams are attached below)

I have tried few solutions given below but still I am facing the same issue.

I have tried several resistance values, but no gain. Of course, if I increase the value too much, then the TRIAC doesn't even trigger in the positive half. But for the negative half, even low resistance values don't work.

Can anyone please guide me on what I am doing wrong here? Many thanks.
[image]

Comment: You need to tell  us what the MCU is doing.

Comment: MCU is giving pulses to the MOC3020 for each positive and negative cycle. I can clearly see the pulses for both halves (in almost the middle of both cycles), but the MOC only responds to the positive cycle.

Comment: wnich triac are you using?

Comment: I second this - which triac and what is your 100W lamp? Incandescent?

Comment: @Kartman Thanks for commenting. I am using BTA16 (also have tried replacing with BTA20) and the load is incandescent light bulb, I also have tried putting 1000W heating element. Both have same waveform across them.

Comment: @Jasen I am using BTA16, have changed all components. Also have replaced with BTA20 but no gain.

Comment: try running the lamp at full power using just a resistor to VCC to power the MOC3020, find out how much current it needs.

Comment: When lamp runs at full power (220 VAC rms), it consumes 0.48A.

Answer (score 0):

If you out the load on the "cold side" you may need snubbers as shown in the bottom circuit.  Otherwise, try placing your load on the "hot side" as shown in the top circuit.

[image: from datasheet of your opto-triac]

Answer (score 0):

Try increase the LED current (and maybe pulse length if it is marginal). The MOC3020 is the least sensitive triac driver of that series and can take as much as 30mA to trigger (15mA typical at room temperature). The opto-triac is not necessarily perfectly symmetric.

Most MCUs cannot drive that much current reliably so you may need a BJT or MOSFET to drive the LED.

Answer (score 0):

### TRIAC triggering with resistive load

You don't need a phase shift capacitor at all for a resistive load. Look at any of the [datasheets](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1806097.pdf).
If you are using an MCU to define the timing, you don't want any phase shift imposed by an external network.

Also note that for resistive starting the resistor values are typically much lower.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have used the circuit from Fig. 5. I am having the same issue, nothing changed in the output.

Comment: How are you deriving your Zero crossing Sync pulses? Are you using 50Hz or 100Hz triggers for the MCU?

Comment: I am using 100Hz triggers (triggering both for positive and negative halves of AC sine wave). I have tried reducing MOC Led resistor but same issue (which is obvious as it is working perfectly for positive half)

Comment: I suggest setting up a test bench with a safety transformer (24-32VAC) and just use the MOC3020 with a resistive load. You can safely probe this type of setup to check all your logic and timing. It may be that your main TRIAC is not working or not as sensitive as you expect. What device is your main TRIAC?

Comment: I am using BTA16 in that particular circuit but I have tried BTA20 as well, same response. For MOC3020 testing, should I connect 100W bulb directly to the MOC pin 4 and check ? (The max output current for MOC3020 is 1A, I'll be safe ?)

Comment: No, the MOC2030 should not be used for the 100W load, but it will drive a 1-1.5W load, so if you use 32VAC then use a 470 Ohm load. AS a follow up, how short is the turn on pulse you use? You should turn the LED on for the whole time from trigger time till just before the zero crossing. If you don't then you can have output transients created when the TRIACs fall beneath their holding current.

Comment: Yes, I have tried turn-on pulses from 1ms to 8ms (for each positive and negative half) for a 50Hz main frequency, but same result. 1 point, when I keep the trigger pulses always ON, it passes whole sine wave to the load but if a fire it at any other angle, it just allows positive half while completely blocking negative.

Comment: The BTA16 is not a sensitive gate TRIAC.... gate current may be up around 50 mA. To check your BTA16 is still working in Q1-Q3 connect the gate to A2 with a 470 Ohm resistor, It should turn on on both half cycles with just an offset of about 20V from each zero crossing.

Comment: Yes, it is turning ON in both Q1 and Q3 when I connect the gate directly to A2 with 470 Ohm (Lower values up to 120 also yield same result). Same is true when MOC is always ON, but when I trigger, it blocks negative. :(

Comment: Then you definitely have a gate drive problem. What is the turnon voltage on each cycle?

Comment: I have tried angles from 0 to 180 degrees, all of those angles perfectly trigger in positive half.